# Seasons in which all teams in a division made the playoffs

Tags: trivia, history, nba, postseason

During the 2014-2015 NBA season, each team in the [Southwest Division](http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Div.html?ls=iref:nba:gnav) (Houston, Memphis, San Antonio, Dallas, New Orleans) of the Western Conference made the playoffs.

**Has this happened before? If so, in which seasons has all teams in a division made the playoffs?** I recognize there was a [realignment](http://www.nba.com/news/realign_031117.html) that took place for the 2004-2005 NBA season, but during the 2003-2004 NBA season, *almost* all teams in the Midwest division (6 of 7 teams) of the Western Conference made the playoffs.

Comment: The east was so bad that year... only 2 teams in the west wouldn't have made the playoffs in the east, and I wouldn't be surprised if either one would've won enough more games playing the weaker competition to have won the 7 or 8 more games needed to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. The 2005-2006 Season, the 1985-1986 season, and the 1983-1984 season.

In 2006:

> All five teams in the Central Division made the playoffs, marking the first time all teams in a division made the playoffs since the entire Midwest Division made it 20 years before. [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005-06_NBA_season)

In 1986:

> All Midwest Division teams make the playoffs, the first time an entire division had done this since the 1983-84 season when all Atlantic Division teams made the playoffs. [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1985%E2%80%9386_NBA_season)

In 1983, playoff expansion resulted in the entire Atlantic division making it:

> The NBA Playoffs were expanded from 6 teams per conference to 8, where it stands to this date. As a result, the 'first round bye' system was eliminated. [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983%E2%80%9384_NBA_season)

Comment: So, 2005-2006 and 1985-1986?

Comment: Also 83-84.  And that is it since the realignment in the 1960s where there were no divisions

Comment: Edited the original answer for completeness

Comment: Is there a source for this answer?

Comment: @pacoverflow there was a wikipedia source that was quoted that had been removed (see revisions)

Comment: @edmastermind29 That source only mentions the 05-06 and 85-86 seasons.  How do we know the 83-84 season is the only other one?

Comment: @pacoverflow It's not particularly hard to look at the standings for each year if you want to see if it's correct or not.  The 1983 year makes sense, because prior to 1983 only six teams made the playoffs from each conference, making it a lot less likely.

Comment: @Madmanta You need to source quotations.   Otherwise it's plagiarism.  Please do not edit out others' sourcing of your quotations.

Comment: Ah thanks @Joe for the edit, I was going to come back when I saw the source request and link to the three wikipedia entries that clearly showed the answers.